# IP falls in CIDR range

Tags: c++, c, ip

I have an IP like this: 12.12.12.12
I'm looping through different IP ranges (in 12.12.12.0/24 (example)) format, and trying to see if the IP is in the range.
I have tried various methods such as inet_addr and comparing but I can't seem to get it.
Is there an easy way to do this? I'm using Windows.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507579/how-can-i-determine-that-user-ip-address-is-in-accessible-range-or-not

Comment: That's PHP, as you can see from the tags i'm using C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just test whether:

```
(ip & netmask) == (range & netmask)
```

You can determine the netmask from the CIDR parameters `range/netbits` as follows:

```
uint32_t netmask = ~(~uint32_t(0) >> netbits);
```

Comment: a `ntohl` conversion could be required before doing this.

Comment: @KillianDS: I'm assuming that the parsing process yields an address in local byte order, but you're right, it is something to double-check, especially since `inet_addr` returns network byte order.

Comment: Do you see something wrong here? Seems to print for every single one: `int cidr = atoi(cdrbuf);

  unsigned long ulstart = ntohl(inet_addr(clip));
  unsigned long ulcheck = ntohl(inet_addr("12.12.12.12"));
  unsigned long netmask = ~unsigned long(~0ULL >> cidr);

  if((ulcheck & netmask) == (cidr & netmask))
   printf("%s\n", pch);`

Comment: @seth: What you do get from `printf("%08x %08x %d\n", ulstart, ulcheck, cidr);`?  But the mask is supposed to test `range` (or `ulstart` in your naming), not `cidr`.

Comment: Ben, many like this:00000224 0c0c0c0c 15
00000824 0c0c0c0c 13
00002024 0c0c0c0c 14
00802524 0c0c0c0c 17
00402624 0c0c0c0c 18
00202724 0c0c0c0c 19
00402724 0c0c0c0c 18
00002824 0c0c0c0c 14
00003424 0c0c0c0c 14
0000c024 0c0c0c0c 11
0000e024 0c0c0c0c 12
0000f024 0c0c0c0c 13
0000fc24 0c0c0c0c 15

Comment: @seth: For one thing, the byte order of `ulstart` is wrong, but that doesn't explain 100% matching.  Print out netmask also (using `%08x`).

Comment: @seth: rats: The shift was shifting in ones, if 0ULL was more than 32 bits.  Fixed my answer.  Or use @bitmask's formula of `(~0U) << (32-cidr)`

Comment: `unsigned long ulstart = ntohl(inet_addr(clip));
  unsigned long ulcheck = ntohl(inet_addr("12.12.12.12"));
  unsigned long netmask = ~(~unsigned long(0) >> netmask);` `if((ulcheck & netmask) == (ulstart & netmask))
   printf("%08x %08x %08x %d\n", ulstart, ulcheck, netmask, cidr);` dfffe500 0c0c0c0c 00000000 24
dfffe600 0c0c0c0c 00000000 24
dfffe800 0c0c0c0c 00000000 22
dffff000 0c0c0c0c 00000000 24
dffff400 0c0c0c0c 00000000 22
dfffff00 0c0c0c0c 00000000 24

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3803/discussion-between-seth-and-ben-voigt)

Comment: @seth: `netmask` should be calculated from `cidr`, not itself.  But the final comparison involves `netmask`, not `cidr`.  Should be `uint32_t netmask = ~(~uint32_t(0) >> cidr); if((ulcheck & netmask) == (ulstart & netmask))`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ZuOr2 where the formula correctly produces a non-zero netmask.

Comment: `~uint32_t(0)` is a funny way of writing `0xffffffffu`.

Comment: @caf: If by "funny", you meant "portable".  What if `int` is 16-bits on the target platform?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Then `0xffffffffu` will have type `unsigned long`, and still have the same *value*.  Read up on the rules for constants.

Comment: @caf: "The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be
represented."  Ok, you're right, so why do you see people tagging `ULL` on the end of literals all the time?  (apparently I use too many different languages, I tend to use patterns that work in all of them).  Anyway, my version definitely IS portable.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: You might use `ULL` if you are going to do something like left-shift the constant, where promotion won't occur.  In this case, either formulation is portable.

Answer (score 2):

Take the binary representation and zero out what is not matching your network mask.

Clarification:
Let's say you have the IP `a.b.c.d` and want to match it to `e.f.g.h/i` then, you can throw the IP into one unsigned integer, `uint32_t ip = a<<24 + b<<16 + c<<8 + d` and do the same with `uint32_t range = e<<24 + f<<16 + g<<8 + h`. Now you can use your network mask: `uint32_t mask = (~0u) << (32-i)`. Now, you can simply check if `ip` "is in" `range` by comparing them: `ip & mask == range & mask`.

Comment: The iteration evidently comes from testing against a whole mess of ranges.