# How to determine whether my internet IP belongs to a given IP list using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ip, cidr

I have following IP list (in CIDR format) stored in a TXT file:<

```
58.200.0.0/13
202.115.0.0/16
121.48.0.0/15
219.224.128.0/18
...
```

But I don't know how can I determine whether my IP belongs to this list. I use the Qt C++ framework on Windows platform.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?
Break down your problem into simple steps, and complete them one by one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to break up each CIDR notation range into a network (the dotted IP address) part, and a number of bits.  Use this number of bits to generate the mask. Then, you only need to test if `(range & mask) == (your_ip & mask)`, just as your operating system does:

Some psuedo-C code:

```
my_ip = inet_addr( my_ip_str )            // Convert your IP string to uint32
range = inet_addr( CIDR.split('/')[0] )   // Convert IP part of CIDR to uint32

num_bits = atoi( CIDR.split('/')[1] )     // Convert bits part of CIDR to int
mask = (1 << num_bits) - 1                // Calc mask

if (my_ip & mask) == (range & mask)
    // in range.
```

You can probably find a library to help you with this.  Boost appears to have an [IP4 class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4.html) which has `<` and `>` operators. But you'll still need to do work with the CIDR notation.

Ref:

- [IP falls in CIDR range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559803/ip-falls-in-cidr-range)

Answer (score 6):

Walking through the Qt Documentation, I came across QHostAddress::parseSubnet(const QString & subnet), which can take a CIDR-style IP range and is new in Qt 4.5. Thus I could write the following code to solve it: (assume myIP is of type QHostAddress)

```
if(myIP.isInSubnet(QHostAddress::parseSubnet("219.224.128.0/18")) {
    //then the IP belongs to the CIDR IP range 219.224.128.0/18
}
```

As for better understanding and insights into the problem, @Jonathon Reinhart 's answer is really helpful.

Comment: +1 Good job finding this. I would definitely use the built-in functionality where it exists (and works). But I'm glad I could provide some insight for you.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers have already covered conversion from text to IP address class. You can check the range by using [QHostAddress::isInSubnet()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qhostaddress.html#isInSubnet-2). This returns true when your IP address is within the address and mask provided.

For instance, here is an example which checks if an IP address is [zeroconfig](http://upe.acm.jhu.edu/websites/Andrew_Pile/) (169.254.1.0 to 169.254.254.255):

```
bool IsZeroconfig(const QHostAddress &ipAddress)
{
    QPair<QHostAddress, int> rangeZeroconfig = QHostAddress::parseSubnet("169.254.0.0/16");

    if (ipAddress.isInSubnet(rangeZeroconfig))
    {
        QPair<QHostAddress, int> preZeroconfig = QHostAddress::parseSubnet("169.254.1.0/24");
        QPair<QHostAddress, int> postZeroconfig = QHostAddress::parseSubnet("169.254.255.0/24");

        if ((!ipAddress.isInSubnet(preZeroconfig)) && (!ipAddress.isInSubnet(postZeroconfig)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 Ah, I didn't know QT had anything like this. More straightforward than my answer :-)